# Reason for different SQL performances for same code on identical servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, ssms, difference

I am complete desperate with a performance differential and I have absolutely no clue WHY there is one.

**Overwiew**
VMware Workstation v11 on my local computer. I gave the VM just 2 cores and 4GB memory.
Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 with two 6-core-Xeon's (older ones) and 64GB memory. Just this VM is running with full hardware associated. 
Referring to a CPU-benchmark I started in each VM, the VM within Hyper-V should be about 5x faster then my local one.

I stripped my code down to just this one operation which I set in a WHILE-loop to simulate parallel queries - normally this is done by a webserver.

**Code**

```sql
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1
WHILE @cnt <= 1000
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION Trans
        UPDATE [Test].[dbo].[NumberTable]
        SET  Number = Number + 1
        OUTPUT deleted.*
    COMMIT TRANSACTION Trans
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END
```

When I execute this in SSMS it needs:
VMware Workstation: 43s
Hyper-V Server: 59s
...which is about 2x slower although the system is at least 4x faster.

**Some facts**

1. the DB is the same - backuped and restored
2. the table has just 1 row and 13 fields
3. the table has 3 indexes, none of them is "Number"
4. logged in user is 'SA'
5. OS is identical
6. SQL Server version is identical (same iso)
7. installed SQL Server features are the same
8. to be sure Hyper-V is not the bottleneck I also installed a VMware ESXi v6 on another server with even less power - the result is nearly identical to the Hyper-V-machine
9. settings in SSMS should be identical - checked it twice
10. execution plan is identical on each machine - just execution time is different
11. the more loops I choose, the bigger is the relative time difference
12. **ADDED** when I comment out the OUTPUT-line to suppress the drawing of the line (and each value) my VMware Workstation does it in under 1s while the Hyper-V needs 5s. When I increase the loop number to 2000, my VMware Workstation needs one more time under 1s, the Hyper-V-version although needs 10s!

When running the full code from a local webserver the difference is about 0.8s versus about 9s! *...no, I have not forgotten the '0.'!!*

Can you give me a hint what the hell is going on or what else I can proof?

---

**EDIT**
I tested the code above **without** the OUTPUT-line and with **10,000** passes. The client statistics on both systems look identical, except the time statistics:

**VMware Workstation:**

```sql
+-------------------------------+------+--+------+--+-----------+  
|        Time statistics        | (1)  |  | (2)  |  | (3)       |  
+-------------------------------+------+--+------+--+-----------+  
|   Client processing time      | 2328 |  | 1084 |  | 1706.0000 |  
|   Total execution time        | 2343 |  | 1098 |  | 1720.5000 |  
|   Wait time on server replies |   15 |  |   14 |  | 14.5000   |  
+-------------------------------+------+--+------+--+-----------+
```

**Hyper-V:**

```sql
+-------------------------------+-------+--+------+--+------------+
|        Time statistics        |  (1)  |  | (2)  |  | (3)        |
+-------------------------------+-------+--+------+--+------------+
|   Client processing time      | 55500 |  | 1250 |  | 28375.0000 |
|   Total execution time        | 55718 |  | 1328 |  | 28523.0000 |
|   Wait time on server replies |   218 |  |   78 |  | 148.0000   |
+-------------------------------+-------+--+------+--+------------+
```

(1) : 10,000 passes without OUTPUT
(2) : 1,000 passes with OUTPUT
(3) : mean

---

**EDIT** (for *HLGEM*)
I compared both execution plans and indeed there are two differences:

**fast system:**

```sql
<QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="24" CompileTime="0" CompileCPU="0" CompileMemory="176">
    <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="104842" EstimatedPagesCached="26210" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" />
```

**slow system:**

```sql
<QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="24" CompileTime="1" CompileCPU="1" CompileMemory="176">
  <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="524272" EstimatedPagesCached="655341" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="10" />
```

Comment: [`sp_whoisactive`](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2012/03/22/released-who-is-active-v11-11.aspx) and check when your loop is running to see details about LATCH, blocking and so on, Also I think your query need `table spool` each time. Show execution plan for update

Comment: Check also how your tempdb are configured.

Comment: Try to compare the performance of an SQL statement without output and see what the benchmark says. Make sure to include Client Statistics and compare those. Otherwise, it might be that it merely takes longer to transfer the `output` from the server to your local SSMS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472794/query-taking-more-time-on-local-ssms-than-remote/28474612#28474612

Comment: @Ralph I posted the result in my question. The difference is huge, but how can I determine the reason?

Comment: @lad2025 As far I can see the settings are identical.
I tried to use it and I get a lot of ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait reasons but the most websites write about network problems. In my case this cannot be, because I work locally and even if I disable the network card  the situation is the same.

Comment: Compare IO performance and index fragmentation in both machines

Answer (score 0):

Did you check hardware fully?
It looks as OUTPUT operator spend some time to show data to you.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Time differences depend on many things. A local server may be faster because you are not sending data through a full network pipeline. Other work happening concurrently on each server may affect speed.

Typically in dev there is little or no other work load and things can be faster than on Prod where there are thousands of users trying to things at the same time. This is why load testing is important if you have a large system.

You don't mention indexing but that too can be different on different servers (even when it is supposed to be the same!). So at least check that.

Look at the execution plans see if you can find the difference.  Outdated statistics can also result in a less than optimal execution plan too.

Does one of the servers run applications other than the database? That could be limiting the amount of memory the server has available for the database to use.

Honestly, this is a huge topic and there are many many things you should be checking. If you are doing this kind of analysis, I would suggest you buy a performance tuning book and read through it to figure out what things can affect this. This s not something that can easily be answered by a question on the Internet; you need to get some in depth knowledge.

Comment: **I added a comparison of the execution plans to my question.**
I know, this is why I am running the command locally to avoid more problems due to network or other systems.
Indexing was not relevant for me, because I deleted and recreated both database before the tests and tested the 5th run.
On my local machine with an i7-4770K there are 2 vm's running, about 40 tabs in chrome and about 6 other apps in foreground. AND my VM is restricted to just 4GB memory and 2 cores. Therefore the slow system is running alone on a Hyper-V-Server with 2 Xeon x5650 CPUs and 64GB memory.

Answer (score 0):

Query speed has little to do with CPU/memory speed, especially queries that update data.

Query speed is mainly limited by disk I/O speed, which is at least 1000 times slower than CPU/RAM speed. Making queries faster is ultimately about *avoiding* unnecessary disk I/O, but your query must read and write every row.

The VM box (probably) uses a virtual drive that is mapped to a file on disk and there is probably some effort required to keep the two aligned, possibly even asynchronously, while other processes are running and contending with the drive.

Maybe your workstation has less contention or a simpler virtual file system etc.

Comment: Both SQL SERVER are running as virtual machines - one in VMware Workstation on my local Windows 8 and the slower one on Hyper-V Server. So both are dealing with virtual hdd's. BUT I would say, that this one row is kept in memory, no?

Comment: Oh, right. Still, there might be contention with other hosted VMs or who knows what slowing down the I/O.